# Best practice for master-detail Insert data in biz layer?

Tags: .net, database, transactions, insert, master-detail

Do you have any offer for master-detail insert data into database? Do you use Transaction? What is the best practice for it?  How do you control it in biz layer?

Comment: In what kind of application? Winforms? Webforms? Give more detail on how the user enters and then saves the data.

Comment: Well, in a Winforms application. That form is related to one table as master and 4 tables as its details. I'm looking for the best way for inserting data into these related tables. Do I use transaction or it's not necessary?

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the business rules.  If it is ok for one insert to happen but not another then a transaction is not required.  If however the business rules mean that each insert must occur together than yes, use a transaction.

Best practice is to understand and document the problem being solved to a sufficient degree to understand the situation and then design something that reflects that understanding - therefrore without the context we can not give a specific best practice recommendation.  Although you could try to describe the context of the question and see if we can then be more specific